# Copy a range from excel and paste in WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

in a coded UI test I am trying to copy a dynamic range from excel using range.copy and paste it in wpf grid  by ctrl + v.

here is the code for copying the data from xls

```
            var xlSheet = (Worksheet)excelApp.Worksheets[sheetName];
            excelApp.Worksheets.Select();

            XlRange = xlSheet.UsedRange;
            XlRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
```

and Here is the bit to paste it on wpf grid 
I click on start cell and then do a ctrl v to paste

```
Mouse.Click(targetCell);
Keyboard.SendKeys(CreateMdRebalWindow, "V", ModifierKeys.Control);
```

But for whatever reason  its not pasting it..  data is copied alright in clipboard  because if I open a new sheet and do a ctrl v manually.  it pastes the values there..

any pointers..?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I am not allowed to comment on your question, so I will have to post an answer.

I see that you are using a capital v ("V").
Should you not be using a regular v ("v")?

Comment: @ tsteemers I have Tried Both (v V). but same behaviour